# How can i run Get-MgAccessToken in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to run the following

```
 $token = Get-MgAccessToken -ClientId $clientId -ClientSecret $clientSecret -TenantId 
 $tenantId
```

but it gives the error: The term 'Get-MgAccessToken' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.
I have ran the following:  Install-Module -Name "Microsoft.Graph"

Is there a different module i need to install ?  How can i get this to run successfully ?

Comment: Why do you want the token? That cmdlet will already store it for you and make it available to the other cmdlets. Seems like you meant `Get-AzAccessToken`

Comment: There is a powershell cmd Get-MgAccessToken which is the Get Microsoft Graph access token , that is what i am after. I just want to know what  is the correct module to install in Powershell .

Comment: Have you tried using google? If there is a function or cmdlet with that name it is not from the official Microsoft.Graph module. Even if there was, `Get-MsalToken` has been proven to be the better alternative or a direct api call

Comment: Yes have used and followed , but still same issue